# SharePoint list sometimes won't save attachments but the item saves without it, no errors

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a basic SharePoint list, users create a new list item with attachment(s) that are rarely very large, usually small pdf's.

The issue is the new item screen sometimes stays displayed, and you can see the item saved in the background, but the attachment doesn't save at the same time. Sometimes if you wait long enough, the attachment appears on the saved item.

Sometimes is just never appears on the item. I have met with Microsoft about it, I was even able to demo that it happens even with a brand new list with no code at all.

They 'escalated' it a few weeks ago but no news. It comes and goes with no commonality at all. We can go days with no issues, then it happens 5 times in an hour. I have a flow on the list that sends an email when a new item is created, but as I said above, I was able to show that it even happened on a brand new list.

Users were told not to hit the X button or Cancel when the attachment takes awhile to load, but sometimes it just hangs there forever.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does this happen with other SharePoint lists?

Comment: Yup, we had Microsoft on a call to use Fiddler to get a log file, and we created a brand new list and it happened there. It seems to happen at the same time...will be zero issues for 5 days then all of a sudden it happens for a couple of hours. I cannot recreate this morning, but probably can next week....